# how to match two strings with regular expression in bash shell script?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I want to automate some task in a shell script. Among the code I need to make a comparison between two names that share the same digit but differ in one letter. I have a bunch of strings:

```
YC1SM YM1SM YC1SN YM1SN
YC4SM YM4SM YC4SN YM4SN
```

I need to match between the following:

```
$a=YC1SM
$b=YM1SM
```

or

```
$a=YC4SM
$b=YM4SM
```

or

```
$a=YC4SN
$b=YM4SN
```

I need to have an if clause using regular expression basically to do something like this:

```
if [$a matches $b]; then
    command xxx
fi
```

How can I do this match within bash?

Edit:
The names are all the same length. They all differ in just one letter. This differing letter occur at the same position in the strings (here, the second character).

Edit2:
Added more scenario

Comment: Are the names all the same length?  Do they all differ in just one letter?  Does this differing letter occur at the same position in the strings (here, the second character)?

Comment: yes, I just edited it.

Comment: SO YC1SM matches YM1SM ?

Comment: yes, basically i want the digits to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a pattern from variable `a` and match `b` against the pattern.

```
a=YC1SM
b=YM1SM
pattern="${a:0:1}?${a:2}"
echo "$pattern"
[[ $b == $pattern ]] && echo match
```

```
Y?1SM
match
```

If the unmatched char must be a letter, change `?` to `[[:alpha:]]`

Comment: can you explain pattern="${a:0:1}?${a:2}"?

Comment: That is bash's substring syntax. `${a:0:1}` means start at character offset 0 for length 1 (the first char of a). `${a:2}` means start at character offset 2 until the end of the string (from the 3rd char to the end). ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: I tried and it sees that I have to use [[]] instead of [] in the if clause. [] worked for me in the past, at least for two variables. Why is it not working for the pattern now?

Comment: because `==` inside `[[...]]` is a pattern matching operator, and `==` inside `[...]` is an equality operator. If you're using bash, make it a habit to use `[[...]]` -- there's really no down side.

Answer (score 1):

You can have this comparison like this using BASH regex:

```
a=YC123SM
b=YART123JKL

[[ "$a" =~ ([0-9]+) ]] && n1="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
[[ "$b" =~ ([0-9]+) ]] && n2="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

[[ "$n1" -eq "$n2" ]] && echo "same" || echo "not same"
same
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex. Just use the substring operation like this:

```
c="${a:0:1}${b:1:1}${a:2}"
if [[ "$c" -eq "$b" ]]; then
    command xxx
fi
```

The substring operator works like this: `${var:first:length}`
So the first line tkaes the first character of `a`, then the second character of `b`, the from the third character to the end of `a`.

In your case this will create a copy of `a` (called `c`) that will have all of the letters from `a` except it will contain the second character from `b`, which is the only character that you say can be different. Since this character is copied from `b` to make `c`, `c` will now match `b` if that character was the only difference.

Comment: can you explain the first line a little bit?

Comment: Added some explanation to the answer.